# Why is my GroupLayout giving an 'exception in main' error?

Tags: java, grouplayout

I want to use GroupLayout to get a usernameLabel/Field and passwordLabel/Field display, like so:

Username: **usernameField** 
Password: **passwordField**

The code I am using is as follows:

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(usernameLabel)
                .addComponent(usernameField) 
                    )
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(passwordLabel)
                    .addComponent(passwordField)
                    )
            );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(usernameLabel)
                    .addComponent(usernameField)
                     )
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(passwordLabel)
                    .addComponent(passwordLabel)
                    )
            );
```

This compiles but gives me the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.swing.JPasswordField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.apple.laf.AquaTextFieldBorder@5910e440,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=128,g=128,b=128],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=0,g=0,b=0],selectionColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=164,g=205,b=255],columns=20,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,echoChar=●] is not attached to a vertical group
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.checkComponents(GroupLayout.java:1090)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.prepare(GroupLayout.java:1040)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.layoutContainer(GroupLayout.java:910)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1510)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1499)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1695)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1630)
    at java.awt.Container.validateUnconditionally(Container.java:1667)
    at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1033)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at xWing.GUIlogin.<init>(GUIlogin.java:107)
    at xWing.Driver.main(Driver.java:7)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.swing.JPasswordField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.apple.laf.AquaTextFieldBorder@5910e440,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=128,g=128,b=128],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=0,g=0,b=0],selectionColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=164,g=205,b=255],columns=20,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,echoChar=●] is not attached to a vertical group
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.checkComponents(GroupLayout.java:1090)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.prepare(GroupLayout.java:1040)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.layoutContainer(GroupLayout.java:910)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1510)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1499)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1695)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1630)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2744)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

*Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?*

[Resource 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148958/building-gui-using-grouplayout-in-java): I compared my logic ( i.e. the grid logic I used to decide which group should be parallel / sequential ) to the answer in this and it *seemed* to be right. 
[Resource 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693741/grouplayout-giving-error-with-java-swing)

Comment: This is just my opinion, but GroupLayout doesn't lend itself well to hand coding and was designed for form editors, personally, I avoid it in favour of other options

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for commenting =) Will take what you said into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(passwordLabel)
                .addComponent(passwordLabel)
                )
```

That looks wrong.  Why add the label twice?

And if one of those is supposed to be `passwordField`, that may explain why the exception says that there is a `PasswordText` object that is not attached to a vertical group.

Answer (score 1):

`JPasswordField ... is not attached to a vertical group` says clearly that it is not attached to vertical group.

You have typo here:

```
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(passwordLabel)
            .addComponent(passwordLabel)
            )
```

Using group layout can by tricky. In my experience, i found that it is easier to use 3rd party layout manager for Swing applications like very good [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) It has plenty of documentation and is very easy to use. Try it out.

Comment: +1. Could not choose both of your answers; accepted the oldest answer to break the tie. Thank you very much for commenting, and will check out MigLayout.